# Inserção de registros no banco apenas após finalizar a inserção em uma Lista

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces

Não sei se fui bem específico no título, mas vou tentar ser mais na descrição. Tenho em meu banco de dados uma tabela de Disciplinas que contém:

1. id
2. nome
3. carga horária

Eu gostaria que essas disciplinas fossem adicionadas em uma tabela (no primefaces) onde eu pudesse clicar e ela ir para uma segunda tabela, uma tabela de "escolhidas" por exemplo. E só após eu concluir a escolha, eu poder clicar em Enviar e os registros serem gravados no banco. Estou usando Java, Hibernate e Primefaces, já vi algo parecido mas não consigo achar o componente no ShowCase.

Comment: Não existe um componente que faça tudo isso. Você precisa usar o `dataTable` com `multiple selection`. Da uma olhada em: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml. Nesse caso a pergunta é bem ampla se você espera um código pronto que faça do início ao fim.

Comment: Não não, não quero tudo não. Só preciso de um norte mesmo, porque vi em um video uma vez e vi que era possível. Vou dar uma olhada e ver o que eu posso fazer com a tabela. Valeu!

Comment: @Wakim eu posso fazer mais ou menos assim: Construir duas DataTales, na primeira eu usar os dados que vem do banco e na segunda uma lista de selecionados? Ai conforme for adicionando em uma, vou atualizando na outra? Mais ou menos assim? Só não sei como farei pra atualizar a segunda tabela conforme a primeira vá sendo utilizada.

Comment: Sim, a minha sugestão é ter a primeira tabela populada e configurada com o `selection`. Usando o clientBehavior de seleção (`p:ajax` com evento de `rowSelectCheckbox` ou `rowSelect`, basta ver na documentação o evento correto) ou com um botão mesmo (lembrando do `selection`, que é uma lista do bean), para adicionar os itens no modelo da outra tabela. Supondo que o botão seria feito com ajax (se for por submit, a atualização é automática), basta setar o `update/render` com o id da outra tabela.

Comment: Hmmm, vou tentar fazer isso @Wakim, foi de grande ajuda, obrigado =)